# OS X based RFID Printing Solution

Tags: printing, macos

We are in the process of upgrading our servers at our school. Right now we use [Safecom](http://www.safecom.eu/) to manage our print queues for each user. Each user that is allowed to print can do so via logging in using an RFID printer tag.

What I would like to know is whether there is a similar solution that runs on OS X?

It should be able to:

- Allow users to push their jobs to the printer, collecting them later using the RFID tag to log in.
- Allow administrators to check how many jobs have been sent, cancel jobs, add users and so on
- Allow us to import users from a directory service of some kind